# How do I force Windows CE to re-read registry values that have been updated?

Tags: windows, registry, windows-ce

In Windows CE 5.0, after changing some registry values, the changes don't take effect and I must restart Windows.

How can this be done without restarting Windows?

Comment: It depends on the registry value in question. You need to be more specific.

Comment: The application involved must re-read its settings from the registry. So it depends on the application or dll.

Comment: @David, thanks for your comment. for now i'm working on power management parameters on Windows CE 5.0, but my question is very general, cause sometimes i work on another things in registry and i wanted to know if there is any way to do that.

Comment: Your question might be general, but there is no single general answer.

Comment: You use the official API to modify the value, which automatically causes the system to refresh it. You don't do this by modifying the registry. That's like sneaking in through the backdoor and then asking why you're not greeted by the owner of the house.

Comment: @Cody, Thank you, i'll do your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I was tasked to do this early this week for CE4 so I thought I'd share my findings here (whether or not it's still needed) -- after I updated the registry, I ran this "SaveRegistry.exe" tool from the manufacturer's SDK; see these links for a start and look through your manufacturer's files/setup/install CDs as you may find SDK or sample code: 
http://www.microlise.net/VRC8900net/secondary_html/os_version.htm
 and 
http://www.garz-fricke.de/download.php?fid=380&lg=en 
This tool was done in C++ but you can call the executable from whatever language you used.

Comment: The app most likely just calls RegFlushKey, causing the OS to persist changes - not necessarily make system-level notifications of the changes.  This is also an app specific to your hardware - it's not a standard Windows CE tool/app.

Answer (score -1):

If type of your registry is hive, you may call RegFlushKey API function.

Comment: That won't cause registry key consumers to refresh themselves.